# RestTemplate postForObject response getting truncated

Tags: string, spring, resttemplate

Trying to fetch the response using spring web client, but the result response is getting truncated as the response size is more than that of string class. Is there any other way to get the response without being truncated?

```
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> requestMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        //String response = "";
        try{
            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("ccda", "File");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            IOUtils.copy(ccdaFile.getInputStream(), out);
            requestMap.add("ccdaFile", new FileSystemResource(tempFile));       
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = 
                                        new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(requestMap, headers);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            FormHttpMessageConverter formConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
            formConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(formConverter);
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

            String response = restTemplate.postForObject("localhost:8080", 
                                                requestEntity, String.class);

            tempFile.delete();
        }catch(Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an InputStream
I think you may do in this way:

```
InputStream is = rt.execute("localhost:8080", HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
```

Where requestCallback is an implementation of `org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback`  like this one

```
public class MyRequestCallback implements RequestCallback
{
    @Override
    public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        request.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        request.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    }
}
```

While responseExtractor may by an instance of this class

```
public class MyResponseExtractor implements ResponseExtractor<InputStream>
{
    @Override
    public Boolean extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        HttpStatus status = response.getStatusCode();
        switch (status)
        {
        case OK:
            return response.getBody();
        default:
            return null;
        }   
    }
}
```

Once obtained the InputStream you can manage it
Hope it is usefull

Comment: The inputStream can't be used for the jsonMapping and it is throwing json mapping exception for the inputStream.

Comment: @Vishwaksena are you  consuming a JSON? So I guess you can use the Object directly instead of pasing for a string; I consumed very big JSONs and never had this issues

Comment: I am trying to use the response coming back and it is a JSON, but getting that into a String is getting it truncated.

Comment: configure logging at DEBUG level (or better TRACE) and repeat the call then put the log messages here.. maybe we can get more info

Comment: I am actually hitting a live service and hence kept localhost instead of it and I couldn't fetch the server logs.